# Antivirus is scanning and deleting infinitely generated temp files, causing high CPU usage

Tags: windows, cpu, anti-virus, adware

I am using Windows 10, and BitDefender Free Edition as Antivirus.

Sometimes (it occurred not only once), I hear my CPU Fan spinning at very high speed and when I open my Task Manager to see what's going on, I found that BitDefender is eating up CPU resource seriously.

And then I open up BitDefender console to see what's going on.
And I found that every 1~3 seconds, a few files were either blocked or deleted; all of them from the Directory `C:\Windows\Temp\tmp0000033c\`. File name starting with `temp0000****`.

Full message is like this:

```
item was blocked. Threat name: Adware.GenericKD.3642843. Path:
C:\Windows\Temp\tmp0000033c\temp0000****.
```

Even if I try to delete this folder and files, they are generated immediately again and again.

Since each file is actually quite large (719KB), I try to use Resource Monitor to see what is writing those files onto my HDD. However, what I found is `System`....

So now I have no idea what is the cause of this, but the high CPU usage is really scary.

Is there a way to prevent these files from spawning, or find out what program is spawning these files?

Comment: You are infected with nasty malware, I would do a full disk scan with bit defender.

Comment: Use Defender Offlince scan (in settings app) which reboots the PC into a special mode and scans it here. look if this removes the malware.

Comment: Or rescue media from another anti-malware suite, e.g. free Avast! or Avira, since BitDefender doesn't seem capable of resolving issue. Make the disk or USB drive on a machine that is *not* infected.

Comment: If you are curious, Resource monitor will often show System as handling files, this is pretty normal, but you might try using ProcessExplorer (a free Microsoft SysInternals utility) and search for the Handle to the folder being written to. The program with the handle is the one doing it. But an offline virus removal tool as suggested above is what you *need* to use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, last time I encountered this I did performed a full virus scan but it did not help. I will try doing it in safe mode this time, but BitDefender complains on service not started in safe mode...

Comment: Again, scanning in Safe mode from an infected drive does not always work. Use separately created bootable media.

Comment: @Yorik After a full scan the problem still persist, and I start to use ProcessExplorer to monitor. I tried to use `Find > Find Handle or DLL` and enter the folder name, but no result can be found; and I tried to look at the I/O graph but it seems nothing abnormal, does I/O counts only internet or is actually HDD? Actually how do I operate as you suggested ` search for the Handle to the folder being written to`? Many thanks!

Comment: @Yorik Ah, just found that I can separate Internet and Disk. Any more suggestions?